# chat application with group chat feature in jsp-servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets, chat

Hii I am new to **socket** **programming** in **java**...
I have requirement to create a chat application in jsp-servlet
with feature of group chat.

And this group is like pages on facebook in which a user likes the page then can upload something on page and can group chat with members of page,

Now a question how do i manage that page data on which i(Admin) can upload picture/video/status and even users can upload same but it can't get published without admin's permission......

Please suggest me some solutions or give me some references.

Comment: Can v concert applet program to jsp servlet?

Comment: you need to create a layout, for what you wanted to make,you might be asking for how to create it and mangage it but for that show some effrots otherwise no one will get to know in which direction you are moving

Comment: Are you new to programming, or sockets?  In any case, you don't have to use websockets. You could just use regular Ajax.

Comment: I have a chat box having text box and submit button now what helps me in sending message from one user to other using jsp servlet?